# Matrix Algebra looking for 33 and 35

Tags: algebra-precalculus, recreational-mathematics

Looking for $33$ and $35$ using :

- must use : $4 , 4 , 4 , 4$
- optional : $+ , - , / , x , ^ , \sqrt{} , !$ ( can be used more than once )

example for $2$ : $$( 4/4 ) + ( 4/ 4) = 1 + 1 = 2 $$

I'm looking for $33$ and $35$ now.

Comment: There are probably many ways to do this. Have you tried some combinations yourself? Furthermore, if there is no limit to the number of operations, one solution is $\frac{4}{4} + \frac{4}{4} + \ldots + \frac{4}{4}$ where you add them 33 and 35 times. I feel like there are details missing from this question, are you sure you typed it out correctly?

Comment: I'm reading it as the OP means exactly four $4$s, but zero-to-many of the operators.

Comment: OP, what have you tried? Have you tried looking at what useful numbers 33 and 35 are close to? E.g. 33 is $3/4 * 44$, or $4! + 9$, etc. Then see if you can use the remaining $4$s to get from the almost-target number to the target number.

Comment: Why Matrix ????

Comment: You should be clear (if it is true) that one is only allowed four fours in the question.  A better title would be "Four fours looking for 33 and 35"

Answer (score 2):

[This page](https://web.archive.org/web/20171221031659/http://mathforum.org/ruth/four4s.puzzle.html) gives $33=4!+4+\frac{\sqrt 4}{.4}, 35=4!+44/4$, both with four fours.

Answer (score 1):

$$33=4(4+4)+\frac{4}{4},$$

$$35=4(4+4)+4-\frac{4}{4}.$$

Comment: OP wasn't clear, but I believe the question only allows four fours.

Answer (score 1):

Your example gave an answer in itself:
$$\frac44 + \frac44 + \frac44 + \frac44 + \frac44 + \frac44 + \frac44 + \frac44 + \frac44 + \frac44 + \frac44 + \frac44 + \frac44 + \frac44 + \frac44 + \frac44 + \frac44 + \frac44 + \frac44 + \frac44 + \frac44 + \frac44 + \frac44 + \frac44 + \frac44 + \frac44 + \frac44 + \frac44 + \frac44 + \frac44 + \frac44 + \frac44 + \frac44 = 33$$